# Git: How to make an existing git lightweight tag point to another commit?

Tags: git, git-tag

On a test Git repository, `git log` yields:

```
commit e1f972f22f9906ad62007b4e372d8dc06bc47656
Author: davidandreoletti
Date:   Sun Mar 18 11:23:09 2012 +0800
   Added 0

commit 81a07eeffc58b054d4c083a0d7c1d4aa0b0440d5
Author: davidandreoletti
Date:   Sun Mar 18 10:46:44 2012 +0800

   first commit
```

and `git tag 0.0.2` is a lightweight tag pointing to commit `81a07eeffc58b054d4c083a0d7c1d4aa0b0440d5`. All commits have been pushed to a remote repository (tags included).

In this context, how do I make an existing Git "lightweight tag" point to another commit? I.e. I want tag "0.0.2" to point to commit `e1f972f22f9906ad62007b4e372d8dc06bc47656` instead of `81a07eeffc58b054d4c083a0d7c1d4aa0b0440d5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just dump the old tag and create a new one

```
git tag -d 0.0.2
git tag 0.0.2 e1f97...
```

Assuming you have a remote repository that you work with, you'll also need to:

```
git push --tag --force <remote>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't do this. Git will go out of it's way to try to stop you, however

```
git tag -d 0.0.2
git tag 0.0.2  e1f972f22f9906ad62007b4e372d8dc06bc47656
```

Should work if it hasn't been pushed.

Comment: Agreed that this is a generally bad idea and should be avoided. That said, you'll probably have to `git push --force` if the tag has already been pushed.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: In general, I would also avoid doing this but here I am working a single developer project where the developer (me) tagged the wrong commit. Therefore, I think it is perfectly allowed here.

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti In that case yes it's probably okay, but it's good to note for future visitors `:)`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It's worth noting that if you think the head will change, just leave it as a branch not a tag :)